# Quicksort performance in Python - random pivot vs static

Tags: algorithm, sorting, debugging, quicksort

Ok, this is driving me crazy. I created a straightforward Quicksort implementation (from CLR) with random choice of pivot:

```
def qsr(l, s, e):
    def qsrpartition(l, s, e):
        pivotindex=random.randrange(s,e+1)
        l[e], l[pivotindex] = l[pivotindex], l[e]
        p = l[e]
        i = s - 1
        for j in range(s, e):
            if l[j] <= p:
                i = i+1
                l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
        l[i+1], l[e] = l[e], l[i+1]
        return i+1
        
    if s < e:
        q = qsrpartition(l, s, e)
        qsr(l, s, q-1)
        qsr(l, q+1, e)
```

I also have a version with static choice of pivot (comment out the first two lines of qsrpartition). If I run the two versions on a random array, the randomized version above is 100 faster than the one always picking the last element as pivot (1s vs 10s).

```
li = random.choices(range(5000), k=5000)
li2 = random.choices(range(5000), k=5000)
r1 = timeit.timeit(lambda:qs(li, 0, len(li)-1),number=10)
r2 = timeit.timeit(lambda:qsr(li2, 0, len(li2)-1),number=10)
print(r1, r2)

11.10 0.08
```

The result above holds probabilistically across runs, array lengths, use of sample with or without replacement, order in which I run the functions etc. For a random choice of array, the choice of pivot should not matter, as the last element should be as good as any intermediate. I feel that there are an obvious explanation, which I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your benchmarking code is not measuring what you intended.

As already commented, the lists `li` and `li2` are sorted in the first of the 10 runs, and the 9 others are sorting already sorted lists. When a partition is already sorted, then choosing the last entry as pivot represents a worst case, giving the random pivot variant the advantage in 9 out of the 10 runs.

I would also make more runs to get a better estimate.

Here is a correction:

```
k = 5000
runs = 50
print(" qs", timeit.timeit(lambda: qs(random.choices(range(k), k=k), 0, k-1),number=runs))
print("qsr", timeit.timeit(lambda:qsr(random.choices(range(k), k=k), 0, k-1),number=runs))
```

This gives an output that slightly favors the non-random pivot version for the plain reason it doesn't have to execute those two extra statements. On repl.it I got output like this:

```
 qs 2.3873363960025017
qsr 2.9921084540001175
```

Comment: LOL that clarifies it thanks! I got so stuck thinking it must have been a weird bug in the code that I overlooked the most basic thing :-(

Comment: This is also not (just) measuring what they intended, as it includes the time to create the lists, and we don't see how much that is.

Comment: @KellyBundy I also had this concern. When I fixed my code I put the list creation in timeit's `setup` parameter and switched to `timeit.repeat` instead to `timeit.timeit` to ensure setup gets executed before each trial.

Answer (score 0):

You measure drawing random numbers and swap vs. no swap, in addition to static vs. random pick.
To just measure random vs. non-random pivot, don't just comment out the first two lines:
Unconditionally draw that random number, use a static swap (`l[0], l[-1] = l[-1], l[0]`) vs. the random one.

But [Gene's pointed out the main fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226501/quicksort-performance-in-python-random-pivot-vs-static#comment132750047_75226501): quicksorting ordered arrays.
Currently, you are measuring worst case vs. "average"/"random".